# R Markdown density plot error using kable

Tags: r, plot, markdown, kable

I have made some density plots to add to an R Markdown project. Plots work fine in a normal R project, also fine in Markdown, until I tried to use Kable. Then this strange error?

How can I change the size and position if Kable does not work?

Any ideas what is happening here?

Thanks!

[image: erorr]

Comment: why are you trying to use `kable()` to show plot ?

Comment: I guess kable is not the way here....so how do I change position or size of the plot?

Comment: see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html

Comment: okay, thanks...im pretty new to this. I guess I need to create a figure, plot in that figure, and then I can control the size/location etc?

Comment: In the `{r}` chunk you can set `fig.width` and `fig.height` . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634520/specify-height-and-width-of-ggplot-graph-in-rmarkdown-knitr-output

Comment: Thanks...I should have known this, but thanks for the help!